# Jquery keep menu items in one line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a responsive menu that will be in one line and if space shrinks some of the items will be shifted to another div(`more-nav`) and keep remaining items in one line. Till now i am successful to move items to the another div(`more-nav`) when necessary, but when the window size is larger and enough room for shifting the item back to the main div(`.main-nav`) its not working.
You can check the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tintindenmark/pgsbLz9w/32/

### Here is my jquery code blocks

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.main-nav ul').append('<li class="more-nav">more items</li>');
$(window).resize(function() {
    var container_height = $('.main-nav').height();
    var container_width = $('.main-nav').innerWidth();
    var innerWidth = 100;
    var item_height = $('.main-nav > nav > ul > li').outerHeight(true);
    var main_children = $('.main-nav > nav > ul').children('li:not(:last-child)');
    $.each(main_children, function(i, el) {
        innerWidth += $(el).outerWidth();
    });
    var children = $('.main-nav > nav > ul').children('li:not(:last-child)');
    var children_hidden = $('.more-nav').children('li');

    var childcount = children.length;
    if (container_height > item_height) {
        while (container_height > item_height) {
            $(children[childcount - 1]).prependTo('.more-nav');
            container_height = $('.main-nav').height();
        }
    } else if (container_height == item_height) {
        if (container_width > innerWidth) {
            $(children_hidden[0]).fadeOut(200)
        }
    }
    console.log(container_height);
    $('h2 span').html(container_height);
    $('h3 span').html(container_width);
    $('h4 span').html(innerWidth);

 });
});
```

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to mimic css `flex` - see: [flex wrap](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp#flex-wrap)

Comment: @ATD no i dont want menu items to go outside of wrapper or window

Comment: They won't - that's what flex is all about.  In your jsfiddle page, the Typography item moves to the next line under the Home item if I change the width of the output area.  flex does that automatically. In the code, it looks like you create a new item - with a class of "more-nav" - that is positioned under the Home item.  Hasn't flex achieved the same result?